# How to break out of a sandboxed iFrame?

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, safari, sandbox

### 1. What is the issue?

The [`sandbox`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute added for [iFrame](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-iframe-element) elements in HTML5 spec renders any frame breaking/busting/killing method null in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox) (tested with current version of Chrome & Safari) if the flag [`allow-top-navigation`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#sandboxed-top-level-navigation-browsing-context-flag) is not set, even if the flags [`allow-forms`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-forms) and [`allow-scripts`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-scripts) are present.

### 2. What I have tried?

- Any JavaScript method out there, such as `if(top != self)
  top.location.replace(location);`
- Triggering a submit event on a form
  with the `target="_top"` attribute
- Triggering a click event on an
  anchor element with the `target="_top"` attribute. In fact, anchor elements with the `target="_top"` attribute are rendered useless. So, a nice message to advice users to take action won't work either (as shown in this [Flickr iFrame example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/HEaan/)).

### 3. What I want to achieve?

I want a way to break out of frames on modern browsers, which have implemented the `sandbox` attribute for iFrames with the flags `allow-forms` and `allow-scripts` present?

*Seems like they have just given the missing pieces of a puzzle to all black hats with this attribute.*

### 4. What I am not looking for?

I am looking for a solution, which will break out of frames. Not for a solution, which won't display the site inside frames (such as [`X-Frame-Options` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)) or using CSS to hide the body and such.

Comment: *Seems like they have just given the missing pieces of a puzzle to all black hats with this attribute.* Please keep the politics out of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid that you won't find a solution, as the point of the sandbox is that you can't break out of it.

If there was a hack to break out, it would be classified as a security issue by the vendor and patched quickly.

Comment: It's not completely true. Sandboxes are made to be broken (look at iOS jailbreaks and Androoid rooted devices). May be there are no known way to break the latest Chrome and Safari, but I am pretty sure there are known issues with older versions.

Comment: Sure. But the question is about modern browser versions -- all of which have auto-updaters, so the penetration rate of any hack one finds is happily going to drop through the floor.

Comment: @JonathanHedley Actually, I am not looking for a hack. I am looking for a legit way to break out of frames. I am not sure why the hell the drafters of the specs have made it this way, but seems like they are giving leechers (newbie hackers and big corps alike) a fine way to frame us as they wish.

Comment: I understand you're not after a hack. The spec is like this to allow the parent page to safely include content from external sources. E.g. embedding content from video providers, ad servers, social networks, etc. I suggest if you don't want to enable your content to be embedded, use JS to check if you are and just clear your content.

Comment: @JonathanHedley Hmm... I was hoping they would give us much more options than the broken `X-Frame-Options`, which does not allow a full list of exception, and the defacing of our own sites. The way it is now, it's sooo broken, sigh...

However, I am going to go with defacing for now. I hope those crooks  don't disable JS for my framed site. :/

This is not what I was looking for, but I am going to award the bounty to you, because it will be wasted otherwise. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JonathanHedley the point of all security is for it to work, but we always hear of attacks on things people told us were safe. Also, the fact that you think there would be a patch for an attack suggest that any bug found would be an implementation bug, but there are such things as design flaws that can't be patched or are otherwise hard to patch that would be equally has helpful to defeat a security system.